# Need help in editing a awk code to print minimum within range

Tags: awk, range, max, edit, minimum

Thanks to Origineil for his help in modifying the awk script. The awk script work perfetly right if the interval are whole number but if I use an interval of less than one like 0.2, it gives a wrong output. I have a file "sss" containing this data:

```
H34   5.0856    5.45563
H39   5.0857    5.45573
H26   6.4822    6.81033
H30   6.4822    6.81033
H32   6.4823    6.81043
H40   6.4824    6.81053
H33   7.6729    7.96531
H27   7.673     7.96541
H31   7.6731    7.96551
H38   7.6731    7.96551
H29   8.5384    8.80485
H28   8.5387    8.80514
H35   8.5387    8.80514
H37   8.5387    8.80514
H41   9.9078    10.1332
H36   9.9087    10.134
```

If I then run the awk command

```
    awk '!e{e=$2+0.2;} $2-e>0{print "Range " ++i , c " entries. min: " min " max: " max ; e+=0.2; c=0; min=""} {if(!min)min=$2; c++; max=$2} END{print "Range " ++i , c " entries. min: " min " max: " max} ' ss
```

It gives the output with difference between the values are not up to 0.2 indicated in the script:

```
 Range 1 2 entries. min: 5.0856 max: 5.0857
 Range 2 1 entries. min: 6.4822 max: 6.4822
 Range 3 1 entries. min: 6.4822 max: 6.4822
 Range 4 1 entries. min: 6.4823 max: 6.4823
 Range 5 1 entries. min: 6.4824 max: 6.4824
 Range 6 1 entries. min: 7.6729 max: 7.6729
 Range 7 1 entries. min: 7.673 max: 7.673
 Range 8 1 entries. min: 7.6731 max: 7.6731
 Range 9 1 entries. min: 7.6731 max: 7.6731
 Range 10 1 entries. min: 8.5384 max: 8.5384
 Range 11 1 entries. min: 8.5387 max: 8.5387
 Range 12 1 entries. min: 8.5387 max: 8.5387
 Range 13 1 entries. min: 8.5387 max: 8.5387
 Range 14 1 entries. min: 9.9078 max: 9.9078
 Range 15 1 entries. min: 9.9087 max: 9.9087
```

Can somebody help me out on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `minimum` and `maximum` I assume you mean the first and last entry seen within the range.

For the provided input I changed `18` to `17` so that not all "max" values were also the upper bounds of the range.

Script:

```
awk '!e{e=$1+4;} $1-e>0{print "Range " ++i , c " entries. min: " min " max: " max ; e+=4; c=0; min=""} {if(!min)min=$1; c++; max=$1} END{print "Range " ++i , c " entries. min: " min " max: " max} ' file
```

I introduced two variables `min` and `max` to track the entries.

Output:

```
 Range 1 4 entries. min: 2 max: 6
 Range 2 3 entries. min: 7 max: 10
 Range 3 3 entries. min: 12 max: 14
 Range 4 2 entries. min: 16 max: 17
 Range 5 1 entries. min: 19 max: 19
```

Comment: Thanks Origineli, it is exactly what I want